# SQL WHERE "word ... word"

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

Basically, I have a DEPARTMENT table with each department having a `deptname`. I want to grab the deptnum of all departments with the words "Computer ... Science" in their name. It doesn't matter if there are words in between only if they have those two words in the name.

Any ideas of what I should put in my where statement to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `like` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   department
WHERE  deptname LIKE '%Computer%Science%'
```

Comment: Does that allow for words to be inbetween?

Comment: Yes, allows for in between (and words before Computer, and words after Science), but the string Computer must be before Science.

Comment: @Joshm102 '%' is a wildcard in the `like` operator. So basically, this query looks for `deptname`s that are made up of any string (could be empty!), followed by `Computer`, followed by any string (again - can be empty, can be a couple of words, can be whatever), followed by `Science`, followed by any string again.